# Implementing merge sort algorithm issue

Tags: c++

I am implementing a merge sort algorithm and I am receiving an std::bad_alloc in the merge algorithm  and using the cerr statement I have found that my error is in first loop of the merge algorithm. However I am unable to figure out what is wrong.

```
vector<int> VectorOps::mergeSort(vector<int> toSort)
{
    if(toSort.size() <= 1)
    {
        return toSort;

    }
    vector<int> left;
    vector<int> right;

    int half = toSort.size()/2;
    for(int i = 0; i < half; ++i)
    {
        left.push_back(toSort.at(i));
    }

    for(int i = half; i < toSort.size(); ++i)
    {
        right.push_back(toSort.at(i));
    }

    //merge algorithim

    vector<int> toReturn;
    while(left.size() > 0 || right.size() > 0)
    {
        cerr << "The numbers are "<< endl;
        if(left.size() > 0 && right.size() > 0)
        {
            if(left.at(0) <= right.at(0))
            {
                toReturn.push_back(left.at(0));
            }
            else
            {
                toReturn.push_back(right.at(0));
            }
        }
        else if(left.size() > 0)
        {
            toReturn.push_back(left.at(0));
        }
        else if(right.size() > 0)
        {
            toReturn.push_back(right.at(0));
        }
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you start using a debugger since the `cerr` does not allow you to single step execution and look at variables.

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
while(left.size() > 0 || right.size() > 0)
```

The size of `left` and `right` never change (you don't remove the head element) so `toReturn` grows without bound and you run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

As @BenJackson already mentioned in answer...

The size of `left` and `right` never change. You just get the element from the vector and not removed from it. So, the size of `toReturn` grows without bound.

`vector` hasn't any method to remove head element but you can achieve like

```
left.erase(left.begin());
```

For your solution either you remove a head element from vector or only iterate vector and get value.

```
vector<int> toReturn;
int l = 0; r = 0;
while (l < left.size() || r < right.size()) {

    if (l < left.size() && r < right.size()) {
        if (left.at(l) <= right.at(r)) {
            toReturn.push_back(left.at(l++));
        } else {
            toReturn.push_back(right.at(r++));
        }
    } else if (l < left.size()) {
        toReturn.push_back(left.at(l++));
    } else if (r < right.size()) {
        toReturn.push_back(right.at(r++));
    }
}
```

Merge implementation through erasing head element.

```
while (left.size() > 0 || right.size() > 0) {
    cerr << "The numbers are " << endl;
    if (left.size() > 0 && right.size() > 0) {
        if (left.at(0) <= right.at(0)) {
            toReturn.push_back(left.at(0));

            //erase head element from left
            left.erase(left.begin());

        } else {
            toReturn.push_back(right.at(0));

            //erase head element from right
            right.erase(right.begin());

        }
    } else if (left.size() > 0) {
        toReturn.push_back(left.at(0));

        //erase head element from left
        left.erase(left.begin());
    } else if (right.size() > 0) {
        toReturn.push_back(right.at(0));

        //erase head element from right
        right.erase(right.begin());
    }
}
```